# Numpy whole matrix multiply with single row

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy matrices, A and B:

```
A = [[0,-1],
     [-2,5],
     [2,6]]
B = [[5,3],
     [2,4]]
Dimension of A: N * K
Dimension of B: K * K
```

What I want to do is to do marix multiplication with **each row of A** and **the whole B**, and then multiply it with **each row of A** again. Then sum them up.

Which is:

```
N = A.shape[0]
sum = 0
for i in range(N):
    s = A[i] @ B @ A[i]
    print(s)
    sum += s
return sum
```

This print

```
4
70
224
```

And `4 + 70 + 224 = 298` is what I want.
Is there any elegant or pythonic way to achieve this without for loop?
Thanks

Comment: `(A[:,None]@B@A[...,None]).sum()`

Comment: Oh actually `(A@B*A).sum()` is even shorter

Comment: @ZislsNotZis Thanks! This work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('ij,jk,ik->',A,B,A)
```

And optimize it further with `optimize` flag -

```
np.einsum('ij,jk,ik->',A,B,A,optimize=True)
```